# Jenkins Slave using JNLP requires security prompt

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, automated-tests, jnlp

We are using Jenkins to drive automated GUI test in different Virtual Machines. OS is Win7/64 and other Windows variants. The virtual machines are connecting to the Jenkins Master using the JNLP way. Switching to other connections is not possible because the Jobs must execute programs with a GUI.

Thanks to increased security requirements Java is now issuing a dialog to confirm the execution of the Jenkins Remoting Agent. This obviously destroys the automatic execution of the tests. This dialog is presented once in 24 h. Increasing this period of time to a year would solve our problem, too.

The provided details are mentioning different aspects, like
Application's associated file (JNLP) does not have a digital signature

[image]

We are have tried different Java versions (7u67, Java 8u11 and 8u20) and different security settings.

Jenkins is the latest stable 1.565.1 (tried an updated and a newly installed version). A try was given latest Jenkins 1.576 in a fresh install, too.

Is this problem solvable on our side or only on the Jenkins side?
Any ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to use the [Deployment Rule Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/deployment_rules.html). The main difficulty is to create and store certificates at the right place.

## This is step by step guide to solve the above mentioned problem

1. Install Java SDK (v7)
2. Generate Self Signed CA, 50 years valid:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -genkeypair -alias selfsigned -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit -keystore identity.jks -storepass changeit -startdate "2000/01/01 00:00:00" -validity 18262 -keysize 2048
   ```
3. To extract the certificate from the keystore, use this command:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias selfsigned -file Our_CA.cer -keystore identity.jks -storepass changeit
   ```
4. Created ruleset.xml as ANSI file (e.g. use Notepad++):

   `<ruleset version="1.0+">
       <rule>
           <id location="http://url.to.web.server" />
           <action permission="run" />
       </rule>
       <rule>
           <id />
           <!-- The last rule is the default policy and the id should be blank. -->
           <action permission="default" />
       </rule>
   </ruleset>`
5. Convert ruleset.xml to jar file:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\jar.exe" -cvf DeploymentRuleSet.jar ruleset.xml
   ```
6. Sign the jar DeploymentRuleSet.jar

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\jarsigner.exe" -keystore "identity.jks" -signedjar "DeploymentRuleSet.jar" DeploymentRuleSet.jar selfsigned

   verify jar:
   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin\jarsigner.exe" -verify -keystore "identity.jks" -verbose -certs DeploymentRuleSet.jar
   ```

## Switch to the PC where the JNLP app should be launched

1. Copy signed DeploymentRuleSet.jar to C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment

   Folder has to be created on Win7/32.
2. Cleanup C:\Users\\AppData\LocalLow\Sun and C:\Jenkins-Slave\

   Delete the whole folder `C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\LocalLow\Sun` (and Oracle)
   Delete all files in `C:\Jenkins-Slave\` except the batch StartJenkinsSlave
3. Launch Configure Java, switch Security Tab

   Check for link named "View the active Deployment Rule Set". Link must showing the content of the ruleset.xml.
4. Import self signed certificate as Trusted Certificate and Signer CA

   On the Security Tab start Manage Certificates and import the previously exported cert file Our_CA.cer 
   two times. Import it as Trusted Certificate AND Singer CA.

   Manage Certificates -> Certificate Type: Trusted Certificate/Geschützte Zertifikate, Import 
   AND Certificate Type: Signer CA/Signaturgeber CA, Import

Comment: This worked under OS X, but the DeploymentRuleSet.jar goes in `/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment`.